# How would I auto texture map a sphere in OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, mapping, textures

Which parameters for especially s and t would I use to text map a sphere? I've tried various different options, but there's always a little portion that's distorted no matter what values I choose for float[] s and t. I can do planes and cylinders, but I'm not sure about spheres. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    gl.glTexGeni(GL2.GL_T, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL2.GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
    float[] s = {1f, 0f, 0f, 0};
    gl.glTexGenfv(GL2.GL_S, GL2.GL_OBJECT_PLANE, s, 0);
    float[] t = {0f, 1f, 0f, 0};
    gl.glTexGenfv(GL2.GL_T, GL2.GL_OBJECT_PLANE, s, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not texture map a sphere using a single rectangular texture without creating some serious distortion at some place. It's mathematically impossible. That being said, you should not use the `glTexGen` functionality for this either, because a) it's been deprecated, and b) only creates linear planar mappings, whereas for texturing a sphere you need curvilinear coordinates. *Use a vertex shader to generate the texture coordinates from vertex position.*

Comment: Would manual texturing work or is that the same? Something like:
        darkRockTexture.bind();
  gl.glTexCoord2f(3f,2f);...

Comment: @Ali: Manual texture coordinate generation or not, it is **mathematically impossible** to map a connected flat space onto a spherical topology without creating serious distorion or cuts. There's absolutely nothing you can do about it.